# How to replace any thing between http:// and first slash / after http://?

Tags: php, replace

i got a url as string i want to replace anything between **http://** and first slash **/** (in this example i want to replace **proxy-63.somesite.com** with **video2.de.secondsite.net**). could any one tell me how this can be done ?Thanks

**Note:** data between http:// and first slash after it is dynamic so i cant just use replace function!

```
 http://proxy-63.somesite.com/sec(dfgghdfdgd987435392429324343241k)/video/600/500/12345678_mp4_h264_aac_2.m3u8

replaced with :

 http://video2.de.secondsite.net/sec(dfgghdfdgd987435392429324343241k)/video/600/500/12345678_mp4_h264_aac_2.m3u8
```

Comment: FWIW `#https?://[^/]+/#`

Comment: Did you check some regex tutorials before asking this question? Regex is appropriate for this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? PHP has a slew of [string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) and a few [URL functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.url.php).

Comment: You have to show an attempt, you can't just say, please write my code for me

Comment: What should be the relation between the old domain and the new domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original URL can be different each time, the preg_match will find the root.

```
$url = 'http://proxy-63.somesite.com/sec(dfgghdfdgd987435392429324343241k)/video/600/500/12345678_mp4_h264_aac_2.m3u8';
preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i', $url, $domain);
$host = $domain[1];
$newUrl = str_replace($host, 'video2.de.secondsite.net', $url);
echo $newUrl;
```

Comment: the `http://` part shouldn't be optional.

Comment: This duplicates work that parse_url can do for you

Comment: Many thanks to all . After testing i found kevbot solution does the replace correctly. Is there any online tool that help construct preg_match pattern part ?

Comment: @user1788736 Consider using the solution I posted, requires no regex from you, and is a lot less likely to have edge cases problems

Answer (score 4):

You can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$originalUrl = 'http://yourserver';
$parts = parse_url( $originalUrl);
$newServer = 'video2.de.secondsite.net';
$newUrl = $parts['scheme'] . '//' . $newServer . $parts['path'] . '?' . 
          $parts['query'] . '#' . $parts['fragment'];
```

You may have to be more careful and actually test if there is a query and a fragment before blindly adding the # and the ?

And here's a JS solution since I already wrote it down, you don't even have to test for ? and # since they are part of `location.hash` and `location.search`

```
location.protocol + '//' + 'video2.de.secondsite.net' +
location.pathname + location.search + location.hash
```

Comment: uhh... what? This is a PHP question, and it's not a question how to reconstruct the relative (or absolute) URL

Comment: Yeah, I did miss the fact that it was PHP only, leaving it for reference

Comment: how is this reference useful here?

Comment: @JanDvorak Because someone may find this question when searching how to do the same thing in JS

Comment: @JuanMendes no when I search for a PHP solution I don't expect a JS solution and I wouldn't need it. Furthermore, shouldn't you close vote this question as a high rep user ?

Comment: @HamZa wouldn't heavy downvoting be sufficient in this case? The asker does show enough understanding to understand any potential answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't find downvoting effective. It still swarms a lot of crappy answers that seek for rep in cases.

Comment: @Hamza I'm not seeking rep, I'm just leaving it because it may be useful.  If I search for 'how-to-replace-any-thing-between-http-and-first-slash-after-http' I will get this question, PHP or not. In any case, I added a PHP solution

Comment: @JuanMendes I know that, I was talking in general. I mean you're a trusted user now :-) +1 for the php solution

Comment: @JuanMendes normally you include the language in the search. This already excludes this answer from showing in javascript searches, AFAICT

Comment: @JanDvorak Not everybody includes the language when searching. It at least has a qualifier in there now

Comment: They still won't find their answer if they're looking for a C# or Java solution ;-)

Comment: You have a mix of JavaScript and PHP concatenation in your PHP solution.

Comment: @KevBot if you're talking about the `+` for concatenation, that's a minor fix. Done.